# Weird behavior when writing a string to a file

Tags: python

I am trying to make an AutoHotKey script that removes the letter 'e' from most words you type. To do this, I am going to put a list of common words in a text file and have a python script add the proper syntax to the AHK file for each word. For testing purposes, my word list file 'words.txt' contains this:

```
apple
dog
tree
```

I want the output in the file 'wordsOut.txt' (which I will turn into the AHK script) to end up like this after I run the python script:

```
::apple::appl
::tree::tr
```

As you can see, it will exclude words without the letter 'e' and removes 'e' from everything else. But when I run my script which looks like this...

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\jpyth\\Desktop\\words.txt', 'r')

while True:
    word = f.readline()

    if not word: break

    if 'e' in word:
        sp_word = word.strip('e')
        outString = '::{}::{}'.format(word, sp_word)

        p = open('C:\\Users\\jpyth\\Desktop\\wordsOut.txt', 'a+')
        p.write(outString)
        p.close()

f.close()
```

The output text file ends up like this:

```
::apple
::apple
::tree::tr
```

The weirdest part is that, while it never gets it right, the text in the output file can change depending on the number of lines in the input file.

Comment: strip removes the character from beginning and end of string, not from the middle

Comment: Presumably you delete `wordsOut.txt` manually between each run of the script, since you don't clear it out in your code?

Comment: @glibdud I have been deleting the file between tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newline characters in non ASCII encoded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513675/newline-characters-in-non-ascii-encoded-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making this an official answer and not a comment because it's worth pointing out how strip works, and to be weary of hidden characters like new line characters.

`f.readline()` returns each line, including the '\n'. Because strip() only removes the character from beginning and end of string, not from the middle, it's not actually removing anything from most words with 'e'. In fact even a word that ends in 'e' doesn't get that 'e' removed, since you have a new line character to the right of it. It also explains why ::apple is printed over two lines.

`'hello\n'.strip('o')` outputs `'hello\n'`
whereas `'hello'.strip('o')` outputs `'hell'`

As pointed out in the comments, just do `sp_word = word.strip().replace('\n', '').replace('e', '')`

Comment: this really has **nothing** to do with `.strip()` and everything to do with the fact that `.readline()` leaves the `EOL` on the string which is one of the few things I think [Python gets wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: That comprehension is ugly. `sp_word = word.strip().replace('e', '')`

Comment: @feelingunwelcome If you are used to dealing with file data in any meaningful form, then principle of least astonishment would dictate you don't strip characters implicitly. Adding the extra explicit strip() makes the flow clear to a reader. Your misunderstanding of files is not everyones.

Answer (score 0):

lhay's answer is right about the behavior of strip() but I'm not convinced that list comprehension really qualifies as "simple".

I would instead go with replace():

```
>>> 'elemental'.replace('e', '')
'lmntal'
```

(Also side note: `for word in f:`  does the same thing as the first three lines of your code.)